# Creating 2 buttons that reveal content from 2 different direction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create 2 buttons can when clicked will reveal their respective content from 2 different directions.
[image]

**Example:**

When a user click on `smt`, the content will open from the left. 
When a user click on `mi`, the content will open from the right.

So far, I managed to do the `smt` part only as I don't know how to make the "mi" part work.

**Below is my code:**

**Style:**

```
<style>
    .overlay {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 60;
        left: 0;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .overlay-content {
        position: relative;
        top: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .overlay a {
        padding: 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 36px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .overlay .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        right: 45px;
        font-size: 60px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 650px) {
        .overlay a {
            font-size: 20px
        }

        .overlay .closebtn {
            font-size: 40px;
            top: 15px;
            right: 35px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

**SMT button:**

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">Smt</div>
</div>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:680px; left:300px;" onclick="openNav()">smt</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById( "myNav" ).style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById( "myNav" ).style.width = "0%";
    }
</script>
```

How can I re-use the same code for the second button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.. May be this could hep you

> I use `jquery-ui`, function  `slide` to achieve desire effect

**Using single content**

```js
$('#loginPanel').click(function(){
            
                if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {
                   
                   $('#userNav').show('slide',{direction:'left'},1000);
                } else {
                   
                   $('#userNav').hide('slide',{direction:'left'},1000);
                }
});

$('#loginPanel1').click(function(){
            
                if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {
                   
                   $('#userNav').show('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
                } else {
                   
                   $('#userNav').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
                }
});
```

```css
a {
    color: #000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
}

#userNav{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="loginPanel">left-to-right</button>
<button id="loginPanel1">right-to-left</button>

<div id="userNav">User Area</div>
```

**Using separate content** *(i use `flex` to make both content show inline you can just remove class `main-content` to show them on separate line as `block`)*

```js
$('#loginPanel').click(function(){
            
                if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {
                   
                   $('#userNav').show('slide',{direction:'left'},1000);
                } else {
                   
                   $('#userNav').hide('slide',{direction:'left'},1000);
                }
});

$('#loginPanel1').click(function(){
            
                if ($('#userNav1').is(':hidden')) {
                   
                   $('#userNav1').show('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
                } else {
                   
                   $('#userNav1').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
                }
});
```

```css
a {
    color: #000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
}

.area{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    background: #ff0000;
}
.main-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="loginPanel">left-to-right</button>
<button id="loginPanel1">right-to-left</button>
<div class="main-content">
<div class="area" id="userNav">User Area 1</div>

<div class="area" id="userNav1">User Area 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make both buttons to show 2 different content? Like left will show 1 while right will show 2

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the Id to the function like this:

```
onclick="openNav("myNav1")"
```

And if you need to hide element, You can use: display: "none"

```
<script>
    function openNav(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeNav(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to do this for the code:

Add "2" to "openNav", "myNav2", "closeNav2"

```
< script>
function openNav2() {
    document.getElementById( "myNav2" ).style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav2() {
    document.getElementById( "myNav2" ).style.width = "0%";
}
</script>
```

Same for the button code, add "2" to "myNav", "openNav", "closeNav"

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<div class="overlay-content">MI</div>
</div>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:680px; 
left:300px;" onclick="openNav()">MI</span>
```